# What could cause an executable, called by a powershell script, to hang when it exits

Tags: c#-4.0, powershell, freeze

I'm debugging a particularly strange problem...

As a part of my team's test suite, we run a powershell script that calls an executable I wrote in C#.

Every blue-mooned Tuesday, the executable will hang indefinitely until we kill the process. Most days it works just fine, and I haven't gotten it to repro.

The curious part is that this exe hangs after it's done doing all it's work. It's output the last line of data and the main thread is exiting. There's no multithreading in this process, and CPU is at 0% and thread count is 1.

All I/O (other than console writes) is done earlier in the execution, and there's no exception catching anywhere, so if something throws we should see it.

I don't need a definitive "this is the issue," but I have no idea what could cause this behavior. If you could respond with any theories on why this would be happening (no matter how far fetched) that'd be great.

Version info

- OS: Windows 2008 R2
- Powershell: v2 (comes with R2)
- .NET: v4

Comment: Does your C# program use Winforms ?

Comment: There are no winforms. It's all command prompt.

Comment: I found that if you select the text in the console window that you're exe will hang until you press esc. I don't think that's the case in my situation, but it is one reason this could happen.

Answer (score 1):

Heh, this is worth a shot.  Got

```
Console.ReadLine()
```

anywhere at the end of some line of logic?

Answer (score 1):

I've got a behaviour like that on one of my "C" console program. It was well working started via "CMD.EXE" but when I use it via "POWERSHELL.EXE" it hang (systematicaly) at the end of exécution.
In this code, there are keyboard pooling loop (`while (! _kbhit()`), and at the moment I solve the problem by consuming (`getch()`) the keydown that fired the last loop. I don't understand exactly why.

In the Powershell script the result of the exe file is affected to a var.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't take in any input (either keyboard or UI) once the program is called.